# What was the reason to choose the current syntax `import foo.bar.{Baz => _}` to exclude something from import?

Tags: scala, import, language-design, pattern-matching

I wonder if there is a good reason for this optical mismatch between e. g. pattern matching, which uses a simple

```
case foo =>
```

to denote that no action should be taken.

Wouldn't it be reasonable to have something like

```
import foo.bar.{Baz => }
```

instead of

```
import foo.bar.{Baz => _}
```

considering that `_` is used as an "import everything" in the same statement?

Comment: I've never liked "pointing into thin air" in case statements.  Not that this is a reason for the language choice, but I prefer the import style to the pattern matching style!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest it's for symmetry with renamed imports:

```
import java.util.{Collection => JCollection, _}
```

If we want to import to an inaccessible identifier:

```
import java.util.{Collection => _          , _}
```

(I know, `_` is a valid identifier, but on the right hand side of `=>` you should think of it as a black-hole from which the incoming identifier cannot escape.)